# Wobbly windows plugin not working in 17.10

Tags: gnome, compiz, window, 17.10

I have recently upgraded from `17.04` to `17.10`.

Upon upgrading, I noticed the "wobbly windows" feature wasn't working anymore.

I opened the CompizConfig settings manager and the feature was active.

I tried to disable and re-enable with no effect.

I am not knowledgeable enough to figure out whether any of the detailed settings might be the problem - here is a screenshot of what my settings for wobbly windows look like:

[image]

Note: I have tried disabling all other effects, with no change.

Comment: @pomsky thanks for pointing that out. Self-marking as duplicate.

Comment: An upgrade to 17.10 should have moved you to Gnome 3, which doesn't use Compiz.

Comment: @pomsky actually, I can either delete or leave as is given my low rep. Maybe someone can mark it as duplicate for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't worry, others will do that for you.

Comment: @Mena BTW I wouldn't suggest the extension some of answers of the other question suggested. That one looks abandoned now.

Comment: @pomsky yes, I searched a bit and definitely wouldn't go there either. It's just a decorative feature, I don't want to risk breaking things for the sake of cosmetics :)